# How to find error in TCL code

Tags: tcl, syntax-error

I am learning TCL and wanted to know how can I find out errors in my code. I mean what line no is error happening or how can I debug it.

Following is the code which I am trying :

```
proc ldelete {list value}{
    set ix [lsearch -exact $list $value]
    if{$ix >=0}{
        return [lreplace $list $ix $ix]
    } else {
        return $list
    }
}
```

Following is the error i am getting :

```
 extra characters after close-brace
```

I will appreciate the help.

Thanks
aditya

Comment: Keep in mind that **all** commands in Tcl look like this: `command word word ...` where the words are separated by whitespace. That's why spaces around the braces (which group things into words) are crucial.

Comment: This page came up first in a google search for "extra characters after close-brace": http://wiki.tcl.tk/1630

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are running this thus:

`tcl foo.tcl`

then you should be getting an error message telling you that the error is on line 1. (The problem is the lack of a space between the close brace and the open brace.)

As a general rule, if you are working interactively, useful messages (eg the stack trace) are often found in errorInfo, so this is often helpful:

`% puts $errorInfo`

Answer (score 1):

You need a space here

`proc ldelete {list value}{`

`proc ldelete {list value} {`

and here

`if{$ix >=0}{`

`if{$ix >=0} {`

Comment: Also a space between `if` and the condition.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at the contents of the global variable `errorInfo`

```
puts $::errorInfo
```

Relevant documentation links: http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/return.htm and http://wiki.tcl.tk/1645

Answer (score 1):

If you purchase a copy of the Tcl Dev Kit sold by ActiveState, it includes a tool called "tclchecker" which checks for many different kinds of possible problems.

A free alternative, besides frink, is a tool called [nagelfar](http://nagelfar.berlios.de/). It provides a variety of static checks.

Answer (score 0):

I use a static checker called 'frink'. Google for it and you will find it.

UPDATE:
Yes, frink finds many errors I missed. Give me a try.

Comment: hi Vu
Thanks for your suggestion but do you use frink to find out errors in TCL